# How to make g++ to show the execution time in terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I want to make g++ showing me what is the execution time and maybe the return too.

```
g++ file.cpp -o file
./file
```

When i make the executable file and then call in it is showing only the output without the return and execution time.

And i want to make it showing something like this:

```
Process returned 0 (0x0)    execution time : 0.002 s
```

Thank you for the attention!

Comment: Instead say `time ./file` and parse the output as per your needs.

Comment: The shell captures the exit status in the `$?` variable, so `echo $?` shows you the exit status of the most recently executed command. But I don't know how to do it on the Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can measure how long your process takes with the "time" command.

To determine the return value, you can print the value of the $? environment variable after running your program:

```
time ./file ; echo Process returned $?
```

You can also specify how exactly time should format its results with the -f (or --format) option.
However, some Linux distributions might use a bash-builtin time implementation by default which lacks that option, so you might have to give the full path to use the *real* time program:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "Execution time: %E" ./file
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use time command as follows:
 `time ./file`

Answer (score 3):

Look here first: [calculating execution time in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876901/calculating-execution-time-in-c)

You can also use a clock (from `time.h`)in code (although for multi-threaded code it works kinda funny)

```
int a;
unsigned t0 = clock(), t1;
std::cin >> a;
t1 = clock() - t0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). You may use [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) externally (from your shell, like [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22133408/841108) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22133364/841108)). You could also use from inside your program syscalls like [clock_gettime(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) etc...

Don't expect timing to be really meaningful or accurate for small delays (e.g. less than half a second).

BTW, your question has not much to do with the GCC *compiler* (i.e. `g++`). If using a recent [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) with `-std=c++11` you could use [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) etc etc... And even if using these it is not the compiler which is timing your program (but some library functions using [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall))